# Trying to edit a text field in MS Access, but it says it needs more parameters

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, oledbcommand

I'm trying to edit a textfield in an MS Access database. I'm able to successfully edit a number, but if I try to edit a textfield it asks me for more parameters. My code looks like this:

```
try
{
    ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 set Navn=" + txt_navn.Text.ToString() + " where ID=" + txt_userID.Text + "", conn);
    ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 set Niveau=" + txt_niveau.Text.ToString() + " where ID=" + txt_userID.Text + "", conn);
    conn.Open();
    ad.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    conn.Close();
}
```

Basically, the Navn text field won't accept any changes and asks for more parameters if I disable the Niveau line. I've also tried having both within the same `ad.UpdateCommand` line, but that gave me an error.

As it is now it doesn't give any error, but it just doesn't change the 'Navn' field in the database, the 'Niveau' field changes just fine. Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navn` may be reserved, so try to frame it. Also, there should be no reason to cast the text content of a textbox to string. And, as mentioned, one call will do it:

```
ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 Set [Navn] = '" + txt_navn.Text + "', Niveau = " + txt_niveau.Text + " Where ID = " + txt_userID.Text + "", conn);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to have done the trick, i'm still quite novice at database programming, so this wasn't an option i'd have thought of, but thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will do the trick

```
ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 set Navn='" + txt_navn.Text.ToString() + "' where ID=" + txt_userID.Text + ";", conn);
ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 set Niveau='" + txt_niveau.Text.ToString() + "' where ID=" + txt_userID.Text + ";", conn);
```

I have updated `Navn='" + txt_navn.Text.ToString() + "'` instead of `Navn=" + txt_navn.Text.ToString() + "`

And same goes to the next command

But the thing is it would only update `Niveau` and not `Navn` since you have the last command store in the `ad.UpdateCommand` so you can improvise your code like this

```
ad.UpdateCommand = new OleDbCommand("Update Tabel1 set Navn='" + txt_navn.Text.ToString() + "', Niveau='" + txt_niveau.Text.ToString() + "' where ID=" + txt_userID.Text + ";", conn);
```